# Preserving locality in psi-ontic interpretations of QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations

Specifically in the many-worlds interpretation, if the wavefunction is considered to be real before a measurement it seems that locality is impossible.

When the wave hits a detector screen, it would need to communicate with itself faster than light in order to be sure it only hits the screen at one point. Doesn't this mean that many-worlds violates locality?

Since my understanding is that many-worlds preserves locality, I'm wondering what I'm missing.

Comment: Many worlds has no measurement events. It’s just unitary Schroedinger evolution, nothing else. I find that it is better to think of MW as a challenge, rather than as an interpretation. It challenges you to understand all experience and observation using only the S-equation. Opinions differ as the whether this is possible.

Answer (score 2):

> if the wavefunction is considered to be real before a measurement it seems that locality is impossible.

In many worlds the wavefunction is considered to be real after the measurement as well. The whole point is that unitary time evolution describes everything, and the wavefunction is deterministic.

> When the wave hits a detector screen, it would need to communicate with itself faster than light in order to be sure it only hits the screen at one point.

No,nothing special happens when the light hits a detector screen, it doesn't need to "communicate with itself", and it doesn't hit it at one point. What happens under this interpretation is that the light is in a superposition, *but so is the detector*, so what looks like the light hitting the detector is really a superposition of the entire light + detector system.

When you the experimentalist observe one of these superpositions,consider that you are made of matter and therefore obey the laws of physics so you also are in a superposition, and each of your superpositions observe their corresponding light + detector system. The many worlds interpretation is perhaps better referred to as the many observer interpretation. There isn't one point it hits on the screen, and everything is local in the whole configuration space. The observer problem is similar to the problem you have considering the probability of you being born as yourself, it's anthropic in nature.

Comment: But I'm still not sure this explains why we only ever observe one location being registered on the detector. Why can't the particle hit two different locations and be registered as hitting both?

Comment: Because your classical mind cannot be simultaneously aware of two macroscopically different branches of the wave function, such as a cat being both dead and alive, or a detector beeping both here and there. In MW both happen, the state evolves into two ‘copies’ of you, each only aware of one of the possible outcomes. It takes some struggle to abandon the collapse idea and to try to see everything as unitary evolution.

Comment: @10ppb Ok so I'm getting the idea that you can only be aware of one branch, but I don't see why each branch has to have exactly one point on the detector activated. In other words, why are these the "pointer states"? Is there any particular philosophical explanation for why the wavefunction is a superposition of single locations rather than something else?

Comment: The incident wave hits the detector screen everywhere, and there is subsequent evolution of the MW wavefunction everywhere. But a classical screen is utterly incoherent with itself at different locations, so the subsequent evolution at one location is incoherent with evolution at another location. They are distinct incoherent branches of the MW wavefunction. You and your lab notebook can only be correlated with one of the branches.

Comment: You observe only one detection for exactly the same reason as you only see the world through your own eyes and not someone else’s. Your superpositions might as well be someone else.